# VBA Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range; trying to activate another workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to create a VBA in Excel 2010 that takes info from another spreadsheet that I'm not allowed to alter and bring it over to the spreadsheet with my macro built in. Here's my code:

```
Sub BringUpWorkbook()
    Workbooks("RITE 1624.xls").Activate
End Sub
```

I have several VBA books, have visited dozens of sites on the Internet, including those here at stackoverflow.com, and cannot find a reason why I'm receiving the run-time error. The workbook is already open, I've tried adding everything trailing the title, I've tried removing the `.xls`, I've even did all of the above with in a variable. Any ideas?

Comment: Loop through the workbooks collection and debug.print their name property.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Looked up several `debug.print` examples and I don't understand how to do that with my current example shown above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure the extension is correct. If it's a excel-2010 file like you indicate, you may need to update your code to reflect the extension of your "RITE 1624" file (e.g. .xlsx for a 2010 Excel workbook, .xlsm for a 2010 Excel macro-enabled workbook, or whatever the extension is.

```
Sub BringUpWorkbook()
    Workbooks("RITE 1624.xlsx").Activate
End Sub
```

***EDIT:***

To make sure you have the right name of the workbook, you can print the name of each workbook in an immediate window.

Open up the VBA editor, and then press Ctrl+G to open the Immediate Window (or do View > Immediate window). Then run the following Macro:

```
Sub OpenWkbkNames()

For Each Workbook In Workbooks
    Debug.Print Workbook.Name
Next
End Sub
```

Note that this will give you the names of all the open workbooks ***in the same Excel instance as your macro***. If your RITE 1624 file is in a separate Excel instance, then the instance that your macro is in will not be able to see that file (and it won't appear in the output of the OpenWkbkNames code above). The simplest way to resolve this is to open all of your necessary files from the Excel instance that contains your macro.

```
Sub BringUpWorkbook()

    Workbooks.Open("RITE 1624.xls").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: The file I'm trying to activate is an `.xls` file and I can't make any updates or changes to it. Unfortunately, many examples on the Internet are for Excel 2003 and 2007, as well are my VBA books. The company I work for just upgraded to 2010, so I don't have much of a choice.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I meant to say change the extension that you use in your code, not the extension of the original file. Nonetheless, I would take  the advice of @Tarik and debug/print the names of the files; If that runs as expected, you'll need to do a character by character check.

Comment: I've tried that. Not sure how to use `debug.print`. It didn't give me a pop up or anything...with the exception of the run-time pop up I keep getting. Can you show me in your example how you'd use `debug.print`?

Comment: Ok...I entered your code into a new editor and it said the workbook that I put the code in is the only open workbook, but I have 7 of them open for various reasons. I also had to Dim Workbook As Variant in order for the above code to execute. Was that supposed to happen?

Comment: Must have been a computer glitch. I shut down, restarted, and tried your code again. THIS time, it worked. Thanks.

Comment: debug.print prints to the "Immediate Window" inside the VBA editor. Click the view Tab to activate it and see what is written after you run JayCal's code.