# VBA add FreezePanes to open file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stuck. Try to add FreezePanes to all my excel files.
I have 28 folders "municipalities" in each folder 16 files: 1first, 2second,...
All filese Excel 2003 formats, and are divided into two types - with a figure in the title and without. Each file has several pages.
In parent directory i create file "base" in each two pages "municipalities" and "FilesList" and macro "Sub AddTo Freeze()"

```
Sub addToFreeze()
    x% = firstDataBaseString
    Do While Application.Workbooks(thisFileName).Worksheets("municipalities").Cells(x, 2) <> Empty
        y% = firstDataBaseString
        actMun$ = Application.Workbooks(thisFileName).Worksheets("municipalities").Cells(x, 2)
        Do While Application.Workbooks(thisFileName).Worksheets("FilesList").Cells(y, 1) <> Empty
            actFile$ = TrimFormats(Application.Workbooks(thisFileName).Worksheets("FilesList").Cells(y, 1)) & addedToMunicipal & ".xls"
            openWaN$ = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & actMun & Application.PathSeparator & actFile
            Dim fileHaveNum As Boolean
            fileHaveNum = HasNumber(Application.Workbooks(thisFileName).Worksheets("FilesList").Cells(y, 1))
            If FileExists(openWaN) Then
                Dim openApp As Excel.Application
                Set openApp = New Excel.Application
                openApp.DisplayAlerts = False
                openApp.Visible = True
                openApp.ScreenUpdating = False
                Dim openBook As Workbook
                Set openBook = openApp.Workbooks.Open(openWaN)
                For Each ws In openBook.Worksheets
                    ws.Unprotect Password:="P$n177"
                    afName$ = TrimFormats(actFile)
                    sName$ = ws.Name
                    Workbooks(afName).Worksheets(sName).Activate
                    If fileHaveNum Then
                        Range("G4:G4").Select
                        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
                    Else
                        Range("G6:G6").Select
                        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
                    End If
                    ws.Protect Password:="P$n177"
                Next
                openBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
                openApp.ScreenUpdating = True
                openApp.Quit
            End If
            y = y + 1
        Loop
    x = x + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Every tyme when i try run macro his say "Subscript out of range". Or add FreezePanese to my "base" file....

Comment: on which lines do errors occur i.e. on which line does each occur?

Comment: Workbooks(afName).Worksheets(sName).Activate

Comment: And please use Option Explicit at the top of your code and declare all your variables

Comment: Yep thisFileName is Thisworkbook.Name. I now it's horrible.

Comment: Not horrible just a little confusing and, for me, harder to debug; and you always want Option Explicit.

Comment: What are values of afName and sName when the error occurs? Do they exist? And is the workbook activated first before the worksheet? Think that is required.

Comment: Activate the workbook first then separate line Activate the sheet

Comment: Hm his print "Out of Range" add open file say  - "1first_svod [Read-Only] [Compatibility Mode] - Excel". It is important?

Comment: So it now errors on the worksheet activate line?

Comment: If it errors on the workbook line, do you have the correct file extension?

Comment: No, when i try activate Workbooks - "Workbooks(afName).Activate".
afName = "1first_svod" and open file "1first_svod"

Comment: See comment above

Comment: It could well be using a different file extension e.g. for an earlier version of Excel e.g. xls

Comment: Sory for my english. Im try first activate workbook then sheet. But he does not give me this. I do not understand why he swears, like the names coincide.

Comment: I dont can change formatl all my files because many people in other city use Ms Office 2003.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193153/vba-run-time-error-9-subscript-out-of-range-trying-to-activate-another-workb

Comment: To make sure i use "Debug.Pring openBook.name".  And get the name "1first_svod.xls". Then print next line code Workbooks("11first_svod.xls").Activate. But anyway get error "Subscript out of range".

Comment: Maybe someone more experienced can help. From the link I mentioned it said make sure the workbook is activated from the workbook containing the code (ThisWorkbook) as this is the more recent version. You appear, I think, to be doing that, though worth checking. You also have EnableEvents switched off so notification re file versions shouldn't be a problem. Sorry I am not sure how to advise further. @Jeeped?

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: you didn't waste my time. I just don't have enough experience with this type of problem. Someone likely will. :-)

Comment: I solved the problem =)

Comment: Excellent! Well done. Please post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Dont use

```
Dim openApp As Excel.Application
Set openApp = New Excel.Application
Dim openBook As Workbook
Set openBook = openApp.Workbooks.Open(openWaN)
```

Need use

```
Dim openBook As Workbook
Set openBook = Workbooks.Open(openWaN)
Workbooks(openBook.Name).Activate
```